# Asian option IV less than vanilla option IV

Tags: implied-volatility, asian-option

I was wondering whether the following handwaving line of thought can be used to show that the IV of an Asian option is less than the IV of a vanilla option with the same strike and time to maturity:

For simplicity I'll take $r=q=0$. Furthermore I am going to assume (as pointed out in the comment by Kevin) that the asset $S_u$ is a diffusion (no jumps).

The price of an Asian option is
$$
E_0\left[ \left( \frac1T \int_0^T S_u\, du - K\right)_+ \right].
$$
According to the intermediate/mean value property for integrals, there exists *at least one* $t \in[0,T] $ such that
$$
S_t = \frac1T \int_0^T S_u\, du.
$$
Let $t^*$ be the first such $t$. It's clear that $t^*$ will be a random variable which is always less than or equal to $T$.

We can therefore write
\begin{align}
E_0\left[ \left( \frac1T \int_0^T S_u\, du - K\right)_+ \right] &= E_0 \left[ \left( S_{t^*} - K \right)_+ \right] \\ &\leq E_0 \left[ \left( S_T - K \right)_+ \right].
\end{align}

I think this is OK, but I still have some lingering doubts as $t^*$ is a random time.

Does anyone spot a blatant error above? Better yet, would someone be able to make make the 'proof' more rigorous (if it is correct) or point out where it is incorrect?

Comment: why is $S_{t^*} \leq S_T$?

Comment: @MainCom It's stated nowhere that $S_{t^*} \leq S_T$. What is stated is that $t^* \leq T$ under all scenarios, and hence $E_0 (S_{t^*}-K)_+ \leq E_0 (S_T-K)_+$.

Comment: Doesn’t the mean value theorem for integrals follow from continuity? Extra care for jump models may be required?

Comment: I dont see why that is true.

Comment: @Kevin yes, no jumps. I will edit.

Comment: @MainCom Can you be more specific? I am also not entirely sure what I wrote is correct, but perhaps for other reasons than yours.

Comment: I mean I dont see how could one conclude that inequality $E_0(S_{t^*} - K)_+ \leq E_0(S_{T} - K)_+$.

Comment: Doesn't it follow from the fact that the expectation of a call option increases with maturity? We show that the Asian option is equivalent to a Call option with some maturity t* that is smaller than T, so if you wanted to price the Asian option you ought to use an Implied Vol that's implied from a call option C(k, t*) rather than C(k, T).

Comment: Intuitively, I can follow your ansatz. Obviously, the Asian feature is smoothing away the interim variation until $T$ and the Asian underlying behaves 'like' a shorter-term European underlying. But what about a world where $S_{t^*}$ is larger than $S_T$, on average? Is that ruled out by some other property, i.e. do we "only" need to assume no-calendar-arbitrage opportunity; or a monotoneously increasing total variation or some such?

Comment: Nice question and ansatz, by the way. +1

Answer (score 1):

Your proof relies on the following claim:
Let $t^*$ be a random variable that takes value in $[0,T]$, then $E_0(S_{t^*} -K)_+ \leq E_0(S_T -K)_+$ holds.

Counter example:
Let $t^*$ be the last (or first, does not matter) time when $S$ achieves maximum on $[0,T]$. It is a random variable that takes value in $[0,T]$. However obviously $E_0(S_{t^*} -K)_+ \geq E_0(S_T -K)_+$ since $S_{t^*} \geq S_T$.

Comment: The maximum of S has nothing to do with this. It's about application of the mean value theorem.

Comment: I know what you mean. But how do you prove the last inequality in your proof? What I wrote down is about why something like this does not hold generally.

Comment: i.e. you cannot deduce the expectation is smaller just because $t^* < T$.

Comment: See this thread: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/69568/proof-of-calendar-spread-inequality/69582#69582

Comment: They are different. As you already have mentioned, here t is a random variable. I have already given you a counter example why this is WRONG.

Comment: One last comment on this: I repeat, the maximum of $S$ has nothing to do with this. You define $\tau^*$ as the first/last time $S$ achieves a maximum. I define $\tau^* \in[0,T]$ as the first time such that $$S_{\tau^*} = \frac{1}{T-t}\int_t^T S_u \, du$$ because that is what, path wise, the mean-value theorem implies. That's quite a difference don't you think?

Comment: If you are proving it holds for your specific choice of $\tau^*$ only, that's fine, but you didn't give the proof.  What you did is just claiming it is true, which is definitely not in general for an arbitrary random variable $\tau^*$ that takes value in $[0,T]$.

Comment: Just think of the following: why the last inequality holds for your $t^*$ but not mine? where does the difference come into the proof (about the last inequality)?

Comment: I second @FridoRolloos on this: $t*$ is the last (maximum) time where $S$ equals the average $A$. This time,though stochastic, is smaller than $T$. On that level, I can follow the idea.

Comment: That's irrelevant. Take a look at my choice of $t^*$. It is also smaller than $T$. Please explain why the "no calendar arbitrage" cannot be applied to it to prove the same inequality.

Comment: @MainCom Ah, now I think I am starting to understand your point. Will think about this more. Working with random times is quite subtle it seems.

Comment: I think the difference lies herein: your random time does not equal / is not based on the value of a random variable at time  $T$  whereas my random time is. But as I wrote will need to mull on this.

Comment: Glad you finally get it. Anyway, the whole point is "no calendar arbitrage" cannot be applied to random time in general. In order to prove it for your specific choice of $t^*$, I doubt one could circumvent the situation by mean-value theorem without going back to the original definition of the process $S$ itself.

Comment: Unlike you I am a very slow learner. Took some time to finally get your point, although I am not convinced yet mean value theorem cannot be applied. As I said I am slow.

Answer (score 1):

Undeleting and editing my own answer, not to bump the question up again, but to try to close / settle it as I think there are some interesting subtleties in it.

I'll also briefly address @MainCom 's counterexample to show that in fact it isn't a counterexample.

As I'd like to use the mean value theorem I'll assume that the asset process is continuous on $[0,T]$. For example a local stochastic volatility model without asset price jumps will satisfy this condition.

For simplicity I've set the risk-free rate and dividend yield to zero.

We will be interested in vanilla options
\begin{equation}
C\left(S_t,t,K,T\right) := E_t \left[ \left(S_T - K\right)_+ \right],
\end{equation}
and Asian options
\begin{equation}
C\left(A_t,t,K,T\right) := E_t \left[ \left(A_T - K\right)_+ \right],
\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}
A_t := E_t \left[ \frac1T \int_0^T S_u \, du \right] .
\end{equation}
Let $BS\left(S_t,t,K,T,I_S (K)\right)$ denote the Black-Scholes (BS) price of a vanilla option with implied volatility (IV) $I_S (K)$, and $BS\left(A_t,t,K,T,I_A (K)\right)$ the BS price of an Asian option with IV $I_A (K)$. These IVs are defined by
\begin{align}
BS\left(S_t,t,K,T,I_S(K)\right) &:= C\left(S_t,t,K,T\right), \\
BS\left(A_t,t,K,T,I_A(K)\right) &:= C \left(A_t,t,K,T\right). 
\end{align}

Lastly, recall also the mean-value theorem for integrals: Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Then there exists at least one $x\in[a,b]]$ such that
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(u)\, du.
$$

**Proposition:**

An upper bound on the price $BS\left(A_t,t,K,T,I_A (K)\right)$ of an Asian option is
\begin{equation}
BS\left(A_t,t,K,T,I_A(K)\right) \leq \lambda \, BS\left(S_t,t,\lambda^{-1}K' ,T,I_S(\lambda^{-1}K')\right),
\end{equation}
with $\lambda = \frac{T-t}{T}$ and $K' = K - \frac1T \int_0^t S_u \, du$.

*Proof:*

We can write
\begin{align*}
BS\left(A_t,t,K,T,I_A (K)\right) &:= E_t \left[ \left(A_T - K\right)_+ \right] \\
&= E_t \left[  \left(\frac1T \int_0^T S_u \, du - K \right)_+ \right] \\
&= E_t \left[  \left(\frac{\lambda}{T-t} \int_t^T S_u \, du - K' \right)_+ \right] 
\end{align*}
with $\lambda = \frac{T-t}{T}$ and $K' = K - \frac1T \int_0^t S_u \, du$. According to the mean-value theorem, for each path of the asset, there exists at least one $\tau\in [t,T]$ such that
$$
S_\tau = \frac{1}{T-t} \int_t^T S_u du.
$$
Let $\tau^*$ be the first such $\tau$. It is clear that each $\tau \in [t,T]$ is a random variable, and in particular $\tau^* \in [t,T]$ is a random variable. The problem of determining the price of an Asian option can then be re-cast in the following form:
$$
BS\left(A_t,t,K,T,I_A (K)\right) = \lambda E_t \left[  \left(S_{\tau^*} - \lambda^{-1}K' \right)_+ \right].
$$

Denote by $q(r)$ the distribution of $\tau^*$. Then
\begin{align*}
BS\left(A_t,t,K,T,I_A (K)\right) &= \lambda \int_t^T E_t\left[ \left(S_{\tau^*} - \lambda^{-1} K' \right)_+  | \tau^* = r \right] q(r)\, dr
\end{align*}

Now,
\begin{align*}
E_t\left[ \left(S_{\tau^*} - \lambda^{-1} K' \right)_+  | \tau^* = r \right] &= E_t\left[ \left(E_{\tau^*}(S_T) - \lambda^{-1} K' \right)_+  | \tau^* = r \right] \\
&\leq E_t\left[E_{\tau^*} \left(S_T - \lambda^{-1} K' \right)_+  | \tau^* = r \right] \\
&= E_t\left[\left(S_T - \lambda^{-1} K' \right)_+  | \tau^* = r \right] \\
&=E_t\left[\left(S_T - \lambda^{-1} K' \right)_+\right]
\end{align*}
where the inequality follows from Jensen's inequality, and clearly $S_T$ is independent of $\tau^*$.

Hence,
\begin{align*}
BS\left(A_t,t,K,T,I_A (K)\right) &\leq  \lambda \int_t^T E_t\left[ \left(S_T - \lambda^{-1} K' \right)_+  \right] q(r)\, dr\\
&= \lambda \, E_t\left[ \left(S_T - \lambda^{-1} K' \right)_+ \right]  \\
&= \lambda \, BS\left(S_t,t,\lambda^{-1}K' ,T,I_S (\lambda^{-1}K')\right).
\end{align*}

**Corollary:**
The IV of a freshly minted Asian option is bounded above by the IV of a vanilla option with the same strike and time to maturity.

*Proof:*
For a freshly minted Asian option $t=0$ and thus $\lambda = 1$ and $K=K'$.

As for MainCom's counterexample: Even though it is true that calendar arbitrage cannot in general be applied to random times, it is not a counterexample since the maximum of an asset on $[0,T]$ can't be written as an integral with integral limits equal to $0$ and $T$. This means that the mean value theorem can't even be applied to MainCom's example rendering the whole random time argument non-applicable.

Note that the bounds are in line with the more straightforward derivation given for instance [here.](https://personal.ntu.edu.sg/nprivault/MA5182/asian-options.pdf)
However, I thought applying mean value theorem in this context is interesting as well.

Afterthought: The whole derivation can be shortened to
\begin{align*}
BS\left(A_t,t,K,T,I_A (K)\right) &= \lambda E_t \left[  \left(S_{\tau^*} - \lambda^{-1}K' \right)_+ \right] \\
& = \lambda E_t \left[  \left(E_{\tau^*}(S_T) - \lambda^{-1}K' \right)_+ \right] \\
&\leq \lambda E_t \left[ E_{\tau^*} \left(S_T - \lambda^{-1}K' \right)_+ \right] \\
&= \lambda E_t \left[ \left(S_T - \lambda^{-1}K' \right)_+ \right].
\end{align*}

Comment: Still, you miss the core of the problem. Your claim the inequality follows from the absence of calendar arbitrage is WRONG because here $\tau^*$ is a random variable. To prove it you need to go back to the definition of your process $S$ and make use of property of it.

Comment: @MainCom Why the need to capitalize the word 'wrong' twice now in your comments? Is something wrong?

Comment: Because I want to emphasize it is a fundamental error which you still believe is true.

Comment: I suspect you are the only one thus far who has spotted a fundamental error. That's good.

Comment: If you are unwilling to accept that, you don't need to post the question at all...

Comment: I am not unwilling to accept - but your 'counter example', your answer, is just not clear to me. All you say is that something is 'wrong'. If you are incapable of explaining more clearly then do not post an answer or comment at all.

Comment: answer editted.

Comment: I understand $S_{\tau^*} = E_{\tau^*}(S_T)$ holds unconditionally, but why does it still hold conditional on $\tau^* = r$? Intuitively it seems $E_{\tau^*}(S_T)$ would be greater than $S_{\tau^*}$ if $S_{\tau^*} > S_0$.

Comment: @MainCom In the conditional case, \begin{align*} E_t[S_{\tau^*} | \tau^* = r] &``=" E_t[S_r]\\ &= E_t[E_r S_T] \\ &= E_t[S_T]\end{align*} even though the set of possible values taken by $S_r$ conditional on $\tau^* = r$ is smaller than the set of values taken by $S_r$ unconditionally. It doesn't matter because $S_r$ is regardless still the expectation at $r$ of $S_T$. I initially struggled a bit as well with the fact that the set of possible values of $S$ conditional on $\tau^*$ is smaller than the unconditional set of values.

Comment: I have no problem with $E_{t}(S_{\tau^*}|\tau^* = r) = E_t(E_{\tau^*}(S_T)|\tau^* = r)$, but the equality you wrote is $E_{t}((S_{\tau^*} - K)_+|\tau^* = r) = E_t((E_{\tau^*(S_T)} - K)_+|\tau^* = r)$, I suppose that comes from $S_{\tau^*} = E_{\tau^*(S_T)}$ and this is the part which I don't get.

Comment: @MainCom Because $S$ is a martingale. So regardless of what the value of $\tau^*$ is, $S_{\tau^*} = E_{\tau^*}S_T$.

Comment: It is so, but you have chosen $\tau^*$ to be the time when it achieves mean value, so there's a "condition" implicitly involved.

Comment: Well, sorry but I  don't know how to explain it better than I have already tried. Perhaps another forum member can try.

Comment: Intuitively, if $\tau^*$ is the 'mean value time', and $S_{\tau^*}$ is greater (or smaller )than the average of the value from time $0$ up to $\tau^*$, then I don't understand how could $S_{\tau^*}$ still be the mean value if the expected value of $S$ after time $t^{*}$ are the same as $S_{\tau^*}$.

Comment: possible sloppy disprove: two steps binomial tree starts at $S_0 = 0$, with $S_1=W1$, $S_2 = W_1 + W_2$. Now suppose $\tau^* = 1$ and $S_{\tau^*} = S_1 = 1$, then we must have $S_2 = 2$ instead of $1$.

Comment: If I define $\tau^*$ to be the last time when $S$ achieves maximum, then I suppose you agree $S_{\tau^*} > E_{\tau^*}(S_T)$ by the definition of my choice of $\tau^*$? That's what I mean by "the implicit condition involved matters".