# What is the meaning of an implied volatility of an Asian option?

Tags: implied-volatility, european-options, asian-option

Suppose that an Asian option is quoted OTC in terms of its implied volatility. What is the meaning of an implied volatility in this case? Is it an implied volatility of a vanilla European option with the same price, strike and maturity?

Comment: Maybe the following thread helps. If not, let me know: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/69672/asian-option-iv-less-than-vanilla-option-iv

Comment: I *believe* the VOA is a number $\sigma$ such that if a stock follows a GBM with constant volatility $\sigma$, a MonteCarlo simulation shows that the price of the option would be the quoted price $P_q$. So it is conceptually similar to the "implied BS vol" for an ordinary option. Various methods have been devised for choosing an appropriate VOA in the face of a term structure and skew structure of vol, since the world is not a BS world. See https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3875929 . Can someone who trades Asian Options please confirm?

Comment: Sorrry, I meant VAO (volatility of asian option) not VOA.

Comment: @noob2 From the paper you referenced: The implied volatility of an Asian option σA(K,T) in a given model is defined as that volatility which should be used in the Black-Scholes model in order to reproduce the same Asian price as in the original model4.

Comment: Yes, exactly. By Black Scholes model they mean GBM assumptions (Black and Scholes did not give a formula for Asian options) and whatever method of evaluation you want to use (that is accurate enough). I used MC as an example. What method would you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

Practitioners use Monte Carlo methods, the moment matching method (Levy approximation) and when they want to be super-precise, the [Curran method](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Mike-Curran-2/publication/333906878_Valuing_Asian_and_portfolio_options_by_conditioning_on_the_g/links/5d0bbdec92851cf4403e35c5/Valuing-Asian-and-portfolio-options-by-conditioning-on-the-g.pdf).